# Colored text in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, delphi-10-seattle, opengl-compat

I can get a rotating letter, but cannot color it. Could you check please what is wrong?

```
unit frmMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmGL = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private const
    GLF_START_LIST = 1;
    NUM_LISTS = 1;
  private
    _dc: HDC;
    _hrc: HGLRC;
    _ra: Single;
    procedure _setDCPixelFormat();
  protected
    procedure Paint(); override;
    procedure Resize(); override;
    procedure DoCreate(); override;
  public
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

var
  frmGL: TfrmGL;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.OpenGL, Vcl.Graphics;

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TfrmGL.Paint();
const
  Litera: AnsiString = #0; //The "V" is the first and only symbol in the list, therefore index 0
begin
  inherited;
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -6.0);
  glRotatef(10.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Rotating through 10 degrees around axis X
  glRotatef(_ra, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Rotating around axis Y
  glTranslatef(-0.35, 0.0, 0.1); // Make the letter rotate around its center
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
  glListBase(GLF_START_LIST);
  glCallLists(1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PAnsiChar(Litera));
  glPopAttrib();
  SwapBuffers(_dc);
end;

procedure TfrmGL.Resize();
begin
  inherited;
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(15.0, ClientWidth / ClientHeight, 1.0, 20.0);
  glViewport(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  InvalidateRect(Handle, nil, False);
end;

procedure TfrmGL.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  _ra := _ra - 0.5;
  if _ra < 0 then _ra := 360.0;
  InvalidateRect(Handle, nil, False);
end;

procedure TfrmGL._setDCPixelFormat();
var
  nPixelFormat: Integer;
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
begin
  FillChar(pfd, SizeOf(pfd), 0);
  pfd.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  //pfd.cDepthBits := 32;
  nPixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(_dc, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(_dc, nPixelFormat, @pfd);
end;

destructor TfrmGL.Destroy();
begin
  glDeleteLists(GLF_START_LIST, NUM_LISTS);
  wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
  wglDeleteContext(_hrc);
  ReleaseDC(Handle, _dc);
  DeleteDC(_dc);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmGL.DoCreate();
begin
  inherited;
  _ra := 0;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  _dc := GetDC(Handle);
  _setDCPixelFormat();
  _hrc := wglCreateContext(_dc);
  wglMakeCurrent(_dc, _hrc);
  glClearColor(0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //This does not have any effect
  //makeRasterFont;
  //p1 = graphical device context
  //p2 = from which character to start (86 = code of letter "V")
  //p3 = how many symbols to generate
  //p5 = letter 3D model precision (0 = as in the source font)
  //p6 = 3D depth of the letter
  wglUseFontOutlinesW(Canvas.Handle, 86, NUM_LISTS, GLF_START_LIST, 0, 0.15, WGL_FONT_POLYGONS, nil);
  //Light source initialization
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth test
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); // Enable lighting
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); // Turn on the light source 0
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When lighting ([`GL_LIGHTING`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)) is enabled, then the color which is associated, is taken from the material parameters  ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)).

If you still want to use the current color attribute (which is set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)), then you have to enable [`GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)
and to set the color material paramters ([`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)):

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```

See also [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html).

---

Since the diffuse and specular light depends on the normal vector of the surface, the normal vector attribute ([`glNormal`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml)) which is associated to the vertices, has to be set.
Of course the light parameters [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glLight.xml) have to be set, too.

I've you don't have set the proper parameters, then I recommend to disable lighting. Skip the line:

<s>`glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);`</s>

Once lighting is enabled, the it can be disabled again by

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```